# Trouble logging into this website via Requests Library

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests, passwords

Why I cannot log into this website?

The website I'm trying to log into is: http://boxrec.com/en/login

Here's what my code looks like:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

payload = {
'username': 'username101',
'password': 'password101'
} 

with requests.Session() as s:
    test = s.post('http://boxrec.com/en/login', data=payload)

    r = s.get('http://boxrec.com/en/schedule')  
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
    print(soup)
```

When I call test.cookies, I'm not getting anything from the cookie jar so I'm assuming the login failed.

Another way I know I did not log in successfully is that some part of the websites require user-login to view those information. After I tried logging in, I went to certain part of the website to web-scrape information and see that they're missing because I'm not logged in.

Are the keys to my dictionary correct? I can see that the website names the username box as '_username' for the name and 'username' for the id. Can someone help me confirm the keys that I'm using are correct?

Also, do I need to care about the remember me at all? I tried passing in a True in the dictionary but still no luck. Is there any easy way I can know the parameters that are needed to login?

Comment: Have you done a `s.get('http://boxrec.com/en/login')` before your post to see if that populates any necessary cookies (and obviously checked you've got the form names/values correct)

Comment: I just did a get and it doesn't seem like there was anything in the cookie jar either.

I'm believe I have the form names correct. They have a 'username' for input id and a '_username' for input name. I'm assuming the input id is the correct one, but I tried both and no luck.

Comment: well... use your developer tools in your browser,  and check the traffic that's being sent to the server when you login there and then replicate that data in your dictionary...

Comment: Okay, thanks. I just did a F12 Console on Firefox and found
_target_path,
_username,
_password,
login[go]

Do you think I will need the _target_path and login[go] piece in my payload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form data on that page lists the field names as:

```
_target_path: '',
_username: '',
_password: '',
login[go]: ''
```

try changing the dictionary keys from `"username"` `"password"` to `"_username"` `"_password"`.

I created a test account and was able to login using the code below.

```
from requests import Session

uname = 'zacktest'
password = 'password1'

site = 'http://boxrec.com/en/login'

payload = {
        '_username': uname,
        '_password': password
    }

with Session() as s:
    s.get(site)
    p = s.post(site, data=payload)
    print(p.text)
```

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot!

Do you think I need the target path and login[go]? I just tried changing it to _username and _password but no luck still.

Comment: You could try setting `_target_path: "http://boxrec.com/en/"`. What status code is being returned when you make the post request? How do you know you're not logged in?

Comment: Hmm, still not working still. Because I webscrapped the page after I "logged" in and still see the login button.

Comment: And you can login normally through a web browser? You are certain you have correct username and password? And you're re-scraping while still within `with requests.Session() as s:`?

Comment: Yeah, I logged in via browser to make sure my credentials are correct.

Yes, and I'm using BeautifulSoup to scrap. Here's my code:
    `r = s.get('http://boxrec.com/en/schedule') 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
    print(soup)`

Comment: You might want to update your post with your entire code, excluding your login credentials. I don't have enough info to help you right now.

Comment: Okay, I just updated it. The credentials are fake. Also, thanks for sticking by and trying to help me out, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Updated my post with code. I'm able to login with no issues. Try to login using the simplest code possible. Remove any unnecessary code, such as your `BeautifulSoup` bits.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much A Magoon! Yeah, you're right. I should try to start with the simplest thing first, was jumping the gun a bit and doing multiple things at once. I will try to figure out what went wrong with my code. Thanks again!

Comment: It seems like my problem was that I needed to do a get first, this line: `s.get(site)`